# PHP Dynamic Image Load

Tags: php, image, dynamic

Im trying since some time now to display an dynamic image created with php.
I tried different Tutorials and neither of them is working. The last try i made looked like this:

image.php

```
session_start();
$string = "bla";
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(80,15);
$font_color = imagecolorallocate($img,13,28,91);
$bg_color = imagecolorallocate($img,162,162,162);
imagefill($img,0,0,$bg_color);
imagestring($img, 3, 2, 0, $string, $font_color);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

test.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        session_start();
        echo '<img src="image.php" />';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Saving the image is working and i really dont get what im doing wrong so it loads dynamic. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: none at all if i call test.php, if i call image.php its the "image cannot be displayed because it contains errors" but as much as i already red, its not possible to display in the file its created anyway

Comment: watch for any spaces before `<?php` or after `?>` in image.php

Comment: also, you should probably prevent HTTP caching in image.php if you want to be sure it's dynamic

Comment: it was because of 2 spaces, thought i would have checked that, but meh -.-, thank you alot

Comment: `session_start();` has to come before anything else, as it is with the "headers"

Comment: i will consider the advices you gave me, and thanks again its working now, but is there a way i can close this question without someone or myself needs to answer?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the permissions of the libs on your apache ? also you public cache on the image.php file

```
session_cache_limiter('public');
```

at the beginning of the file

Answer (score 0):

In test.php you call session_start() after some output - html tags.

Session can't start.

Move session_start to top of test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
....
some html code
```

And you not need use echo for output img tag. You can use it as simple html.

I'm guess you don't understand how work sessions in PHP. I recommended you our read some articles about sessions.

Comment: nothing had to do with sessions problem was because of <base